# Where is my model? (saved in project, QGIS 3.10/3.16)

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler

I saved a model (Graphical Modeler) into my project and I don't know where it was saved. How can I get it back?

[image]

Comment: On windows the default will be C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\processing\models you can do save as to change that.

Comment: Yes, but I saved the model to project, not to file. That is a nice function by the way...

Comment: updated with your extra info with a screenshot.

Comment: To answer your first question: it is saved inside your .qgs or .qgz file as xml. @Mapperz already [answered](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/377915/107424) your second one. Alternatively you can open your project file using a texteditor and copy the model part and save it as .model3 file (not very practicable though).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay you need to scroll down on the **Algorithms** Panel.
There is a **Project models** location.

[image]

Comment: The search tool also works for your model name.